# Eevee - How to cast shadow on a background image

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

Using blender 2.80 official release
I want an object to cast its shadow over a plane (to show the right direction) but then i need the plane to disappear, while leaving the shadow as it was and over a background image.

[image]

In the picture i already hve the object and the plane + the image exists as a texture on an actual object.

I found a video from blender guru addresing this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjWoglMYXBE), but i'm not sure how to replicate the effect on 2.80.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Update. Found this video on "Shadow catchers" for EEVEE.
Solved the problem perfectly. Thank you "Blender Pirate"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2WYCZGOCPEY

Comment: Well, please share information here instead of just a link. The idea: this link can be deleted in future. But if you describe the answer here, Stack Exchange will keep it "forever", so that it will be useful for all. Thanks.